# VBA Set custom document property

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some trouble with what I am sure is a quick fix. I have an excel doc with a custom document property field of "Script Status". The script status property comes from a column in the document library from which the doc was downloaded from. My goal is to have a user download the form, complete their assigned task, and then have a "BeforeSave" macro run that will scan the work and update that script status property based on the results of the macro (i.e. if fields are missing, script will say "Not Completed" etc.). In SharePoint, this is a choice dropdown box with the options of: Not Assigned, Assigned, Not Completed, Completed/Pass, Fail, Re-Test, & Deferred. I have the logic on checking the work set and works fine, just not how to update the property field. What I have for that so far is simply:

```
Application.ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Item("Script Status").Value = "Fail"
```

Once it runs, I get an error to the line stating "invalid procedure call or arguement". I have tried to research proper syntax for this line but have been to no avail. Any help would be grateful!

Comment: I can replicate that specific error message if my workbook does **not** contain the named `CustomDocumentProperties.Item`. Verify that your code ensures that this property *exists*, and/or that your code does not elsewhere inadvertently delete it, etc.

Comment: Using code, how would I ensure that the specific property exists? Manually, if I click File I can see the properties on the right side of the screen and that "Script Status" is listed along with all options.

Comment: Before we go down that route... Is the procedure being run from the workbook which contains this property? Or is this macro run from another workbook?

Comment: The procedure is in the workbook with the property. Specifically, it is in the Workbook_BeforeSave declaration. This macro will never be associated with an outside workbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be some quirk about files from Sharepoint, admittedly this is not something I am familiar with, but from reading other threads I know there are some difficulties with these files. This may or may not be the case, here.

In any case, we can try to diagnose it and perhaps we will resolve the problem.

As I mentioned in the comments, I can replicate this error if the named `DocumentProperty` ("Script Status") doesn't exist in my workbook. This could be as easy as a typo, perhaps.  You can use this function to test whether a named `DocumentProperty` exists:

```
Function CustomPropertyExists(propName As String) As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim docProp As DocumentProperty
    Dim propExists As Boolean
    Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
    For Each docProp In wb.CustomDocumentProperties
        If docProp.Name = propName Then
            propExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    CustomPropertyExists = propExists
End Function
```

If you put this in a standard module, you can call the function from the Worksheet like:

`=CustomPropertyExists("Script Status")` and it will return a value of `True` or `False` depending on whether the named property is found.

You could call it from a subroutine, e.g:

```
If CustomPropertyExists("Script Status") Then
    MsgBox "Exists!",vbInformation
Else 
    MsgBox "Does not exist", vbCritical
End If
```

Comment: Thanks David for helping me with this! I tried that function and the return is "Does not exist". Once again though, I can manually go into file>Properties(on the right side) and manually change that property. Then once changed, I can click save and it saves it to our Sharepoint site where you can see the changed status on the website immediately. We are just looking for a way to automate this process. 

It almost seems as if the property is there but in its own seperate area aside from builtin and custom properties? Perhaps it's not a "property" at all and something different?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot (upload an image to imgur.com) to your original question, showing what you are describing when you view the file > Properties?  Maybe that will give me some more info. Or maybe it won't. But at least worth a try.

Comment: So did some messing around and I think I have a solution (knock on wood). I know I haven't uploaded a screenshot yet but for now, if you click File>Info (I am using excel 2010), you see on the right a list of properites (i.e. author, title, etc.) where I can visibily see/modify Script Status. Seeing that the property didn't exist, I set the above line to ActiveWorkbook.BuiltInProperties. Once again, no luck. BUT I then used ActiveWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties and TA-DA, it works. Quirky Sharepoint must not set it as a custom doc prop, but rather a content type (makes sense since it's SP)

Comment: Thanks again for all your work! This was my first post so sorry for asking only to solve it for myself. Thank you again though for sparking my brain to think "property doesn't exist"!

Comment: No problem. If it's been helpful to you, do consider up-voting my answer. Since you arrived at the solution on your own, you can submit your own answer and mark that as the accepted answer, this way other people with similar questions can benefit from the solution that you found.  Cheers.

Comment: Sounds good! My reputation is too low right now to upvote your answer but with 4 more points I will definitely come back and do so. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @NMacioce no need to upvote it if you've accepted it already :)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the Sharepoint property associated with the excel doc is neither a CustomDocumentProperty nor a BuiltInDocumentProperty. Upon dabbling some more with the code, the Sharepoint fields are "ContentTypeProperty". Using the same code posted in the original question with ContentTypeProperty instead of the custom property, the code worked successfully.

Please reference David's code to determine if your "property" is truly a custom property and not a content type. That was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know if this will help anyone, but I was working on saving an .xlsm file to Sharepoint site, which has has Custom Properties set.
I could not find a solution but I managed to sort it out using this.

```
Private Sub SaveToSharePoint()
'set the save location of the document and name
Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = "//sharepoint.com/sites/Shared Documents/"
Dim Type As String: Type = "Doc"
Dim CurrentYear As String: CurrentYear = CStr(Year(Date))
Dim FileName As String: FileName = Type & "_" & CurrentYear & ".xlsm"
Dim FullFilePath As String: FullFilePath = FolderPath + FileName

'Creates the initial file and saves it as .xlsm
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FullFilePath, FileFormat:=52

'Sets the custom properties
ThisWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties("Type").Value = Type
ThisWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties("Year").Value = CurrentYear

'Updates the file
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FullFilePath, FileFormat:=52 End Sub
```