# How to get a custom document property using a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, properties, ms-office

In an Excel formula, is it possible to get a custom document property without an external add-in or help from VBA code?

Comment: What custom document property are you talking about?

Comment: @JvdV I'm talking about [this type of property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406585/vba-set-custom-document-property).  Is that the question?

Comment: Do you mean `=CELL("filename")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to call a macro for that. However, you can link a custom property to the cell content, see [Using “Link to content” to Define custom file properties in Excel](https://www.javelin-tech.com/blog/2013/06/epdm-using-link-to-content-to-define-custom-file-properties-in-excel/) for more information. In that case you could refer to the cell which delivers a custom property value for your formula calculations.

Comment: The external link is used to get more information about connecting a custom property to the cell content. The answer is given.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just display your property in a cell like `{{property_name}}` and use the cell coordinates in the formula.
For example: `=VERKETTEN(""; B3; "test"; B3)`